# how to get sum of time as float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A table has a time column in float datatype is given as:

```
40m
11m
2m
0m
3m
1m
1m
```

How can I sum these values to get it in hours and minutes?

Comment: What is `m`? In C# the `m` suffix designates the `decimal` type. have you stored the time as text? (and not as float as you have stated?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Gordon's answer, which directly leverages SQL Server's built in time ability.  An alternative would be the "brute force" approach of computing the number of hours and minutes represented by the sum of your time column:

```
WITH cte AS (
    -- strip off 'm' units and convert to numbers
    SELECT CONVERT(int, REPLACE(time, 'm', '')) AS time
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(SUM(time) / 60)) + ':' +
    CONVERT(varchar(10), FLOOR(SUM(time) % 60)) AS timestamp
FROM cte;
```

### Demo

The demo shows that the logic holds up even if the number of minutes in your column should exceed 24 hours.

Comment: getting this error Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @kalpna Did you actually store your times as e.g. `10m`, as _text_?  Don't do that please.  Store numerical data as _numbers_.  I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateadd()` and then cast the result back to a time:

```
select cast(dateadd(minute, sum(col), 0) as time)
from t;
```

Note:  This only works up to `23:59:00`.  The SQL Server time type does not support larger values.

[Here](http://rextester.com/PSH66539) is a rextester.